# Map JSON array into java object array

Tags: java, arrays, json

I'm calling API and getting the response as a JSON array I need to map that array into Java object array. Here I've defined the model class below you can see API JSON array, Model class and the way I try to map JSON array into Java object array. I need to make sure if this approach is correct or not.

API response JSON array

```
[
 {
 "sanctionId": 594,
 "listId": "SDN",
 "listType": "SANCTION",
 "publisher": "OFAC",
 "addedDate": "2022-02-11T04:52:59.775+0000",
 "programs": "CUBA",
 "name": " CUBA CIGARS TRADE",
 "title": null,
 "type": "Entity",
 "contacts": [
 {
 "id": 361,
 "address": " ",
 "city": "",
 "state_province": "",
 "country": "Italy",
 "remarks": null
 }
 ],
 "identities": null,
 "remarks": null,
 "other": null,
 "score": 2.1659167
 },
 {
 "sanctionId": 602,
 "listId": "SDN",
 "listType": "SANCTION",
 "publisher": "OFAC",
 "addedDate": "2022-02-11T04:52:59.779+0000",
 "programs": "CUBA",
 "name": " CUBA N CIGARS TRADE",
 "title": null,
 "type": "Entity",
 "contacts": [
 {
 "id": 361,
 "address": " ",
 "city": "",
 "state_province": "",
 "country": "Italy",
 "remarks": null
 }
 ],
 "identities": null,
 "remarks": null,
 "other": null,
 "score": 1.9129416
 }
]
```

Model Class(here I've omitted getters and setters) :

```
    public class SanctionInquiryResponse {

    private String sanctionId="";
    private String listId="";
    private String listType="";
    private String publisher="";
    private String addedDate="";
    private String programs="";
    private String name="";
    private String title="";
    private String type="";
    private String identities="";
    private String remarks="";
    private String other="";
    private String score="";
    private List<Contacts> contacts = null;
}

public class Contacts {

    private String id = "";
    private String address = "";
    private String city = "";
    private String state_Province = "";
    private String country = "";
    private String remarks = "";
}
```

Here is the way I'm trying to map the JSON array into the Java object array

```
String url="http://localhost:8070/getObject";
        
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        //String jsonInString = mapper.writeValueAsString(openCaseRequest);
        
        Client client = Client.create();
        client.setConnectTimeout(120*1000);
        client.setReadTimeout(120*1000);
        
        WebResource webResource = client.resource(url);
        ClientResponse response = webResource.type(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).post(ClientResponse.class);

        String output = response.getEntity(String.class);
        JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(output);
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
            
            sanctionInquiryResponse = gson.fromJson(jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).toString() ,SanctionInquiryResponse.class);
            }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The bellow approach worked for me.

```
public Vector<SanctionInquiryResponse> validateUser(Customer customer) throws ServiceException
{
    SanctionInquiryResponse sanctionInquiryResponse = new SanctionInquiryResponse();
    Vector<SanctionInquiryResponse> VsanctionInquiries= new Vector<SanctionInquiryResponse>();

    try
    {

        String url=SanctionAPIUrl+"/sanction/sanctionInquiry?firstName="+URLEncoder.encode(customer.getFirstName(),"UTF-8")+"&lastName="+URLEncoder.encode(customer.getLastName(),"UTF-8")+ "&address="+URLEncoder.encode(customer.getAddress(),"UTF-8");

        //ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        //String jsonInString = mapper.writeValueAsString(openCaseRequest);

        Client client = Client.create();
        client.setConnectTimeout(Constants.READ_TIMEOUT);
        client.setReadTimeout(Constants.READ_TIMEOUT);

        WebResource webResource = client.resource(url);
        ClientResponse response = webResource.type(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).post(ClientResponse.class);

        String output = response.getEntity(String.class);

        JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(output);
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {

            sanctionInquiryResponse = gson.fromJson(jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).toString() ,SanctionInquiryResponse.class);
            VsanctionInquiries.add(sanctionInquiryResponse);
            Log.debug("sanctionInquiryResponse: "+sanctionInquiryResponse);
        }
        // sanctionInquiryResponse=mapper.readValue(output, SanctionInquiryResponse.class);

        Log.info("Output from validateUser .... \n");
        Log.debug(output);
    } catch (Exception e)
    {
        VsanctionInquiries=null;
        Log.info("ERROR WHILE validating user", e);
        e.printStackTrace();
        //throw new ServiceException("ERROR");
    }
    return VsanctionInquiries;
    }
}
```

Here, I found two different JSON processing libraries in Java that can be helpful in these kinds of scenarios.

1. Jackson library to convert Java objects to JSON.

The ObjectMapper class in Jackson provides methods to serialize Java objects into JSON format and deserialize JSON data into Java objects.

Example usage:

```
ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();

// Serialize Java object to JSON
String jsonString = objectMapper.writeValueAsString(myObject);

// Deserialize JSON to Java object
MyObject deserializedObject = objectMapper.readValue(jsonString, MyObject.class);
```

2. Gson library, another widely used JSON processing library for Java.

Gson provides a simple and flexible API for working with JSON data. The Gson class is the main entry point for using Gson and provides methods for serialization and deserialization.

Example usage:

```
Gson gson = new Gson();

// Serialize Java object to JSON
String jsonString = gson.toJson(myObject);

// Deserialize JSON to Java object
MyObject deserializedObject = gson.fromJson(jsonString, MyObject.class);
```